# Explain the use of 'Malaysia' and '80% urban population'

Tags: meaning-in-context

My freelancer who is a native speaker wrote this:

> In 1970, around one-third of the populations in the Philippines and Malaysia lived in cities. By 2020, **Malaysia** experienced significant growth, reaching approximately **80% urban population**, while **the Philippines** fluctuated between 30% and 50%.

There are two aspects I don't understand.

1. Since Malaysia can't grow and the Philippines can't fluctuate, is it fine to just use 'Malaysia' and 'the Philippines', not '**the city population** in Malaysia and the Philippines'?
2. I don't understand '80% urban population'. I think here we need '80% of the total population'. Can you explain '80% urban population'?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Where did you find this sentence?   The graph says "percentage of the population living in cities".  This would seem to suggest that is what the 80% is referring to.  As written, the example sentence could have been worded better IMHO. It's not wrong, but it's not great either.  You can say things like "this yogurt is 90% milk" - which means the milk makes up 90% of the total yogurt.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thanks for your comment. A freelancer who is a native speaker wrote the sentence.

Comment: if you are not happy with the wording, I think you should speak to your freelancer.  Note also that the sentence is not wrong - there are no errors.

Comment: It seems very clear from context.  "Malaysia" is understandable as "Malaysia *as shown on this graph*" or "the population of Malaysia".  Why do you think countries can't grow or fluctuate?

Comment: "The club is 80% men" would mean that 80% of the members are male, not that there are lots of men cut off at the knee (or neck). The same applies to "80% urban population".

Comment: Thanks everyone. I now understand the meaning of '80% urban population' but I realized I don't understand the grammar. 'Population' is countable. You usually say 'the population' or 'an population'. Why is there no articles in '80% urban population'?

Comment: Countries can grow, and attributes of countries, like their urban population level, can fluctuate. There's two other glaring grammar errors there though. Get a new freelancer.

Comment: @gotube, do you mind telling me what the two other grammar errors are?

Comment: @newbieforever (1) "populations" should be singular, and (2) "experienced" should be "had experienced"

Comment: @gotube, thank you. But we're talking about the populations in TWO countries. And I remember that in another question about 'number of' and 'numbers of', you said use 'numbers of' when there are two different numbers in a year.

Comment: @newbieforever To use "population" as a countable plural, you have to say, "*...the populations **of** the Philippines and Malaysia...*". With "in", it's an uncountable, and refers to the combined population of those two countries as a single mass.

Comment: @gotube, thank you very much. Can you also tell me about the tenses. I understand I should use 'had experienced' with 'by 2020'. What about 'fluctuated'? Should I changed it to 'had fluctuated'?

Comment: @newbieforever All the verbs used with "by" there should be past perfect. Also, Malaysia didn't experience any growth. The *urban percentage of Malaysia's population* experienced significant growth. The data doesn't show whether Malaysia grew as a whole.

Comment: @gotube, thank you so much. About your comment about Malaysia, there is a comment above which says it's clear from the context that Malaysia means the urban percentage of Malaysia's population. And there are also other native speakers who have told me it's clear from the context. So you don't agree? So we have to mention again and agin 'percentage of the city population'? I value your opinion a lot.

Comment: @newbieforever Though it's clear from the full context, including the chart, what the intent of the second sentence is, it literally means that Malaysia itself grew, either in population or area. For the urban population % to grow, it means the rural population % had to decrease. Malaysia itself didn't grow.

Comment: @gotube, thank you very much. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The citizens/residents of a country may live an urban area, think Tokyo and the surrounding, highly populated areas.  Those citizens, along with the residents of Japan's other large cities and the highly populated areas around those cities, are often referred to as the *urban population*.  It's similar to saying *people who live in large cities.*

The Japanese people who live in rural areas on the island of Hokkaido for example, would not be considered part of Japan's urban population.

In your example, when the writer says *the city population* they are drawing a distinction between those who live in cities and those who live rural areas.

80% urban population means that 80% of the total population lives in urban areas.